# Why does appending to the same file from multiple processes work just fine? (NTFS/Python)

Tags: python, windows, concurrency, filesystems, ntfs

The web is full of blogs and discussions about file locking for multiple processes writing to the same file, but I can't find anywhere an explanation why in practice this doesn't seem to be a problem for me.

Specifically I've been trying to destruction test this by having multiple python scripts all append to the same file as fast as possible (tight for loop), and I simply cannot cause an error, nor do I ever see any of the writes corrupting each other (i.e. each line is written completely before the next line beings - the writes appear to be atomic and never interleave bytes).  In some versions of these tests I can end up outputting so much data that I'm generating massive files (GBs+), leading me to believe that for all practical purposes this isn't a problem.

```
# variations on this
for i in range(20000):
    with open("C:/Temp/Test.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write("BBBBn4ls8dhnl,5x8dnthls,ed5hvg,xkdrghx,d85ht,k8hxd4rl,gs8kexdh5lns8exh5.8s4e.8hbxh4y;8s4ehlg8os4e.o8hjex5ln.8hsb45olysghjex4m.o8hbe5,8hlsem.o58ivhsex.4dmo8rehx4.or8awgseh5hse4ysdx5hbr5rdth"*20 + "\n")
```

This feels too much to be a coincidence, and feels like it must have been designed in by someone, but at what level - is it Hardware (SSD are so fast, perhaps some buffering?), drivers, OS, python?

It such a useful feature, that if someone in the stack has gone to the effort of making this work, we should probably be comfortable using it.  But I'd feel more comfortable relying on it if I knew why it worked.

I've been testing on Windows 10, NTFS, using Python 3.8.

**Alternative question:**

Can anyone provide a piece of code that appends to a file and shows multiple appends "interfering" with each other, either by
a) Causing an exception
b) Causing a write to be interupted by another write from another process.  (E.g. so that write("ABCD") and write("1234") result in "AB1C23D4" or somesuch.

Is it even possible?

Comment: when you open file in synchronous mode (you do this), all operation on file is sequential - only one operation per time, new write not begin, until old not finished. all write is "atomic" by fact. you append data - so every operation write to the end of file. so write is not overlap by design. so unclear for what "corruption" you wait. and what you test

Comment: If multiple processes (or multiple threads, each with its own kernel file object) are being tested simultaneously, then it's possible that they could interfere with each other such that writes have overlapping ranges. Each kernel file object has its own file pointer, and Python's append mode is based on seeking the file pointer to the end of the file before writing. To avoid corruption, each process/thread could repeatedly retry acquiring an exclusive lock from the current end of the file up to the number of bytes to write, and keep the range locked even after writing to it.

Comment: It's not clear what *"corruption"* means to you. A file in a consistent state but with unexpected contents? A file that isn't in a well-defined state and cannot subsequently be opened? A file system that's transitioned into an inconsistent state? Something else?

Comment: @ErykSun yes I've seen a lot of comments like this about "it is possible".  The point is I cannot produce any code that actually demonstrates that happening.

Comment: @IInspectable many comments suggest that it is possible that one write could start adding to the file before another write finished, so that the lines would be an interleaved mixture of characters from both writes.  I've clarified the question here, but my point is that never happens.

Comment: @RbMm - but what part of the tech stack is handling that?  I'm spinning up multiple independent processes here, not one python script, and all of them battering the same file at the same time.  Yet it will not break

Comment: io manager. if file opened for synchronous io - all operations on file is serialized. even query it name, will be wait, if write active

Comment: @RbMm, I/O manager synchronization is at the kernel file-object level. Also, if each process/thread has its own file object, then they each have their own file pointer and there's a chance that write ranges will overlap. The timing has to be just right for two contexts to each check the file size at about the same time and issue an `IRP_MJ_WRITE` for the same file offset. Or, if the writes are very large, well beyond the Python file object's buffer size (default 8 KiB), they'll be issued from the processes as interleaved write requests as the buffer in each process is filled and flushed.

Comment: @ErykSun - i thinked that file was opened with `FILE_APPEND_DATA`...

Comment: @RbMm, in my first comment I noted that Python's append mode is not based on the I/O manager and filesystem append mode (i.e. `FILE_APPEND_DATA`). It's based on the C runtime's `_O_APPEND` mode, which opens the file with generic write access and does an `_lseeki64_nolock(fh, 0, FILE_END)` before each write.

Comment: Using the native append mode (i.e. requesting `FILE_APPEND_DATA` access without `FILE_WRITE_DATA` access) eliminates the race condition with seeking the file pointers of multiple kernel file objects to the end of the file. However, large writes to multiple file objects, which get broken up into multiple interleaved IRPs due to in-process buffering, will still be interleaved in the resulting file unless the filesystem coalesces them into a single atomic write per file object.